# mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql

I found this errors repeated in my error log and I believe its causing memory leaks leading to downtimes on my site.

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /mysql.class.php on line 74

PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /mysql.class.php on line 74

PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /functions.php on line 380

PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /functions.php on line 380

PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /mysql.class.php on line 100

PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/glo/mysql.class.php on line 100
```

In mysql.class.php, here is the code from line 72 to 104

```
function &execute () {
    $query = $this->read();
    **$res = mysql_query($query);** // line 74

    if ($res || mysql_errno() == 1062) {
        return $res;
    }
    $mysql_error = mysql_error();
    $mysql_errno = mysql_errno();

    // If debug_backtrace() is available, we can find exactly where the query was called from
    if (function_exists("debug_backtrace")) {
        $bt = debug_backtrace();

        $i = 1;

        if ($bt[$i]["function"] == "SQL_Query_exec_cached" || $bt[$i]["function"] == "get_row_count_cached" || $bt[$i]["function"] == "get_row_count")
            $i++;

        $line = $bt[$i]["line"];
        $file = str_replace(getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "", $bt[$i]["file"]);
        $msg = "Database Error in $file on line $line: $mysql_error. Query was: $query.";
    } else {
        $file = str_replace(getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "", $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
        $msg = "Database Error in $file: $mysql_error. Query was: $query";
    }

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `sqlerr` (`txt`, `time`) 
                 **VALUES (".sqlesc($msg).", '".get_date_time()."')");** // line 100

    if ( function_exists('show_error_msg') )
         show_error_msg("Database Error", "Database Error. Please report this to an Admin.", 1);
}
```

In functions.php here is the code

```
// MySQL escaping
function sqlesc($x) {
if (!is_numeric($x)) {
   $x = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($x)."'"; // Line 380
}
return $x;
}
```

The code for my connection is

```
function_exists("mysql_connect") or die("MySQL support not available.");

@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die('DATABASE: mysql_connect: ' . mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($mysql_db) or die('DATABASE: mysql_select_db: ' . mysql_error());
```

Any help to debug these errors is much appreciated....

Comment: Check if values of `$mysql_host`, `$mysql_user`, `$mysql_pass` are correct...

Comment: From what it sounds you have a Connection Problem. Are you sure that the user is allowed to Access the SQL-Server AND also the appropriate table?  And that there is really NO Password for the user?

Comment: the values of dbconnection are all correct.. site is running as we speak but these errors occur somehow....

Comment: Are you calling any of these function before you have done the connection?

Comment: Also absolutely sure that no Password is required and that the user is not limited to specific ip's? (even if it sounds redundant I had exactly that Problem in the past with similar error Messages and back then I had overlooked it 3 times that a specific IP was set for the user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue here is that the connection is outside of the function's scope and so the mysql functions are attempting to create a new connection without any credentials.

Try assigning your connection to a variable and then calling it as a global within your functions.

```
$conn = @mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);

function &execute () {
    global $conn;
    $query = $this->read();
    $res = mysql_query($query, $conn); 
    ....
```

You can read more about scope in the PHP manual here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Note: Using global variables isn't advised - it would be better practice to use a more OO approach and create the connection in your MySQL class eg:

```
public function connect ($host, $user, $pass) {
    $this->connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
}

function &execute () {
    $query = $this->read();
    $res = mysql_query($query, $this->connection); 
    ....
```

and then using something like this to connect

```
$db = new MysqlClassName();
$db->connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Display errors could be turned off in the php.ini or your apache config file.

You can turn it on in the script:

```
   <?php 
          error_reporting(E_ALL);
          ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ?>
```

write above script in top of page and u will see error message.
You should see the same messages in the php error log.

Comment: So there's nothing wrong with my code, im thinking some of the functions are deprecated...

Comment: Deprecated shouldn't cause an immediate problem (just a few informatory messages).

Comment: I just turned it on, and im seeing so many errors mostly...            Notice: Undefined variable: wait in   Notice: Use of undefined constant in ... these errors are showing once i set to display the errors

Comment: Those errors occur either way. Just they are of low importance (although it is best to fix them) and so ignored by your normal default error handling.